# Numpy rewriting operation using einsum

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am trying to implement PCA in python.
Currently I am using this code to represent the data back into the initial dimensions from the low dimensional data and the principal components:

```
sameDimRepresentation = lowDimRepresentation[:, np.newaxis] * principalComponents.T
sameDimRepresentation = sameDimRepresentation.sum(axis=2)
```

What the code does:

for each row in `lowDimRepresentation` it computes the product between each element of the row (seen as a scalar) and each of the row vectors of principal components (column vectors of `principalComponents.T`) and then it sums all these product vectors up (line 2)

```
lowDimRepresentation: an array of x by 100 
principalComponents: an array of 100 by 784

resulting array: x by 784
```

This method works fine when using x = 10000 but after that I get a memory error.

I know `einsum` is more memory efficient, I was trying to rewrite the same code with it but I did not manage.

Can someone help me with that?

Worst case I just split the 60000 cases into batches of 10000 and I run those bits, but I was hoping to achieve something more elegant.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `numpy.tensordot(lowDimRepresentation, principalComponents, axes=1)` is another way to do what you want.  However, it's slower than `einsum` in this case, and I think you'll hit the same memory problems that @DSM described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there's good news and there's bad news.  The good news is that the `einsum` version is very simple:

```
np.einsum('ij,jl->il', lowDimRepresentation, principalComponents)
```

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = 1000
>>> lowDimRepresentation = np.random.random((x, 100))
>>> principalComponents = np.random.random((100, 784))
>>> sameDimRepresentation = (lowDimRepresentation[:, np.newaxis] * principalComponents.T).sum(axis=2)
>>> esum_same = np.einsum('ij,jl->il', lowDimRepresentation, principalComponents)
>>> np.allclose(sameDimRepresentation, esum_same)
True
```

This should also be a little faster:

```
>>> %timeit sameDimRepresentation = (lowDimRepresentation[:, np.newaxis] * principalComponents.T).sum(axis=2)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.12 s per loop
>>> %timeit esum_same = np.einsum('ij,jl->il', lowDimRepresentation, principalComponents)
10 loops, best of 3: 88.7 ms per loop
```

The bad news is that when I try applying it to the `x=60000` case:

```
>>> esum_same = np.einsum('ij,jl->il', lowDimRepresentation, principalComponents)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: iterator is too large
```

So I'm not sure whether it'll actually help with your real problem..

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I need. I have 12Gb module so this works just fine.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how you got to the einsum conclusion? I managed to understand einsum on simple examples but I am still unsure of how it works with broadcasting

Comment: `'ij,jl->il' works the same as `np.dot` (in 2D).  Internally `einsum` constructs an iterator over `ilj`, with summation on `j`.  The `op_axes` input to the `nditer` constructor is: `op_axes [[0, -1, 1], [-1, 1, 0], [0, 1, -1]]`.  I've written a Python einsum emulator if you want to dig into this more.